# A-frame: get sphere from pool inside <a-videosphere> is Not visible

Tags: javascript, aframe, pool

here the example what bind with Q
    https://jsfiddle.net/91zcdm5r/1/

```
Exact problem: entity is adding from pool well, but it is not showing inside videsphere.

Looks like if videosphere have something like z-index 9999 , it is overlapping a-sphere entity. (not literally but looks like)
```

Think main reason because not possible to add a-sphere inside a-sphere?

Example:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('mainvideo', {
    init: function() {
  //....



        let intersection = this.raycaster.components.raycaster.getIntersection(this.el);
        sphere.setAttribute('position', intersection.point)

 console.log('sphere', sphere) //logs entity ok
//but it is not showing here

/* If try to add explit way like this: 
     //   doc.querySelector('a-scene').appendChild(sphere)
      //fall with core error             
*/

      })
```

What can be done here to showing entity a-sphere Visible.
Please check js fiddle forked from Piotr 
https://jsfiddle.net/91zcdm5r/1/

ps: prev Q. binded with this here
[How is properly to make pool with 10 <a-sphere>s A-frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56618788/how-is-properly-to-make-pool-with-10-a-spheres-a-frame/56638663#56638663)

Answer (score 0):

The spheres are too small to be seen. You can check it by either:
a) Change the `<a-videosphere>` radius from `900` to `100` 
b) Change the spheres scale from `0.1 0.1 0.1` to `5 5 5`

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/t720x8n3/1/) (case b).